# Find the largest $m$ such that $n^{12}\equiv 1\mod m$ for all $n$ relatively prime to $m$? (using only Euler's totient theorem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was able to show that if $(n,72)=1$ then $n^{12}\equiv 1\mod {72}$, and now the second part of this question seeks to find the largest $m$ such that $n^{12}\equiv 1\mod m$ for all $n$ relatively prime to $m$. Based on the first part we must have $m\geq 72$. But I have no idea on how to proceed; any hint would be vastly appreciated. Maybe using Euler's totient function?

Comment: Did you mean $m\ge\color{red}72$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, thanks for spotting the typo

Comment: $m=144$ seems to work

Comment: @J.W.Tanner but how can I find the largest one (or prove that 144 is the largest one if that's the case)?

Comment: $m=65520$ seems to work (it's the product of $16, 9, 5, 7, $ and $13$, which work)

Comment: the Carmichael function of $65520$ is $12$

Comment: I like this question (+1); where is it from?

Comment: @StupidQuestionsInc See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348389/242)

Answer (score 2):

We are looking for the largest $m$ whose [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) is $12$.

The Carmichael function of $m$ is the least common multiple

of the Carmichael function of the prime powers that are factors of $m$.

The Carmichael function of $p^k$ is $\phi(p^k)$ for $p$ odd or $p^k\in\{2,4\},$

and it is $\dfrac{\phi(2^k)}2$ for $p=2$ and $k\ge3$, where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.

The Carmichael function divides $12$ for $m=16$, $m=9$, $m=5$, $m=7$, and $m=13$,

and not for any higher prime powers.

Therefore, the largest $m$ is $16\times9\times5\times7\times13=65520$.

Comment: Is it possible to offer an answer using only the Euler totient function, his theorem, etc?

Comment: I think you need the Carmichael function (at least in concept), as the other (incorrect) answer illustrates:  $\phi(72)=24,$ but $\lambda(72)=6$, which divides $12$

Comment: Typo.  In the final product you forgot the $5$.

Comment: Thanks very much, @ChrisCuster; I edited accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**just an idea**

For each $ n $ relatively prime to $ m $, Euler's theorem allows us to write

$$n^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \mod m$$

So, you can look for the largest $ m $ such that $$\phi(m)=12$$

Comment: good idea, but i don't think that's sufficient, for instance $\phi(72)=24$ and yet $n^{12}\equiv 1\mod{72}$ is also satisfied,